# Boost ElasticSearch score for documents with exact phrase in them

Tags: elasticsearch

So I have the following query:

```
{
  "timeout": 10000,
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
       }
     },
    {
      "rating_avg": {
       "order": "desc"
      }
},
{
  "category_view_avg": {
    "order": "desc"
  }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*iphone 6*",
            "default_operator": "and",
            "fields": [
              "title",
              "description",
              "category_titles"
            ],
            "analyze_wildcard": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "and": [
      {
        "terms": {
          "category_ids": [
            2889732
          ],
          "execution": "bool"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggs": {
    "category_ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "category_ids",
        "size": 15
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query will caclculate the same `_score` for records with titles like so:

- apple-iphone-5-16gb
- apple-iphone-6-plus-16gb-silver-mga92b-a

Is there any way I could add some extra _score points, to documents that have all words of the query side by side in the queried field?

Comment: Try this instead: `"query": "\"iphone 6\""`.

Comment: If it filters out non "iphone 6" results, afterwards you can transform your query in a `bool` with two `should` statements: one will the query you have now, the other will be the query I gave you.